# How can I get a batch of samples from a dataset given a list of idxs in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, dataloader

I have a `torch.utils.data.Dataset` object, I would like to have a `DataLoader` or a similar object that accepts a list of idxs and returns a batch of samples with the corresponding idxs.

**Example**, I have

`list_idxs = [10, 109, 7, 12]`

I would like to do like:

`batch = loader.getbatch(list_idxs)`

where batch contains:

`[sample10, sample109, sample7, sample12]`

Is there a simple and elegant way to do that in an optimized way?

Comment: Should be doable in various ways, but how would this be used in practice?  Normally the way `DataLoader` works is it simply iterates over batches, where the batches returned are determined by both the `BatchSampler` and any other underlying sampler of the Dataset.  You wouldn't need a `DataLoader` for this in principle.  If you already have a `Dataset` of some kind this would simply be equivalent to `batch = [dataset[idx] for idx in idxs]`

Comment: In other words, do you absolutely need any functionality of the `DataLoader` (multiprocessing, collation, etc.) or just some simple custom batching?

Comment: Thanks, yes I need the functionality of DataLoader for preprocessing stuff... the answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could have a `DataLoader` return a sequence of hand-selected batches using a custom `batch_sampler` (you don't even need to pass it a `sampler` in this case).

Given an arbitrary `Dataset`:

```
>>> from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
>>> from torch.utils.data.sampler import Sampler
>>> class MyDataset(Dataset):
...     def __getitem__(self, idx):
...         return idx
```

you can then define something like:

```
>>> class MyBatchSampler(Sampler):
...     def __init__(self, batches):
...         self.batches = batches
...
...     def __iter__(self):
...         for batch in self.batches:
...             yield batch
...
...     def __len__(self):
...         return len(self.batches)
```

which just takes a list of lists containing dataset indices to include in each batch.

Then:

```
>>> dataset = MyDataset()
>>> batch_sampler = MyBatchSampler([[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [4, 2, 1]])
>>> dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_sampler=batch_sampler)
>>> for batch in dataloader:
...     print(batch)
... 
tensor([1, 2, 3])
tensor([5, 6, 7])
tensor([4, 2, 1])
```

Should be easy to extend to your actual Dataset, etc.